# Groupoid $C^*$ algebra of product groupoid

Tags: reference-request, tensor-products, operator-algebras, groupoids

Let $G$ and $H$ be locally compact (Hausdorff, second countable) groupoids with Haar systems $\mu$ and $\nu$, respectively.
Is it true then that the (full) groupoid $C^*$-algebras satisfy
$$ C^*(G\times H, \mu \times \nu) \cong C^*(G,\mu) \otimes C^*(H,\nu), $$
where $\otimes$ is some $C^*$-algebraic tensor product (maybe the maximal one?)?
This fact is hinted at, for example, [here](http://books.google.at/books?id=p_ouxu0j-xoC&lpg=PA105&ots=hR1YlSRlgZ&dq=geometric%20and%20topological%20methods%20for%20quantum%20field%20theory%20two%20locally%20compact%20groupoids%20equipped%20with%20haar%20systems&pg=PA105#v=onepage&q=geometric%20and%20topological%20methods%20for%20quantum%20field%20theory%20two%20locally%20compact%20groupoids%20equipped%20with%20haar%20systems&f=false).

Does anyone know of a reference which contains a proof, or a similar statement under some more restrictive assumptions?
I would also be glad for a reference for the group case.